# Print paper or cellulose - any recyclable filament?

Tags: filament, recycling

I know there is a 3d printing technique, where sheet of papers are cut and glued. Like the ones [Staples](http://www.gizmag.com/staples-mcor-easy-3d-printing/25284/) has in their stores. But this sort of paper isnt recyclable, because of the heavy use of glue.

Is anywhere filament available, which is made of cellulose or other recyclable and bio-degradable material? Or do you know if research is going on in this area?

edit: added bio-degradable

Comment: maybe laywood... I know it's not recycled but maybe it could be, but generally it uses cellulose as it manages wood... with one eye closed... MDF is also wood :)

Comment: thanks for this hint. I read a little about it aaand it is 40% cellulose and rest is bonding agent. for me it looks like the cellulose is for the "taste" or "look" only. But not as the main material....

Comment: I believe the 3D printing technique you are talking about is [Laminated Object Manufacturing (LOM)](http://3dprintingfromscratch.com/common/types-of-3d-printers-or-3d-printing-technologies-overview/#lom)? 

Could you please specify: is your goal to find *any* recyclable 3D printing filament for [FDM](http://3dprintingfromscratch.com/common/types-of-3d-printers-or-3d-printing-technologies-overview/#fdm) printers? In that case, could you perhaps be looking for any kind of PLA material (which is bio-degradable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filament made of Polylactic acid ([PLA](http://reprap.org/wiki/PLA)) is usually made of biological materials (such as corn), and can therefore be considered bio-degradable in most cases.

Whether the filament is 100% bio-degradable (and non-toxic for the surroundings) will depend on the specific formula used by each individual filament manufacturer. (Many manufacturers include various additives to achieve particular effects, such as [glow-in-the-dark](http://3dprintingforbeginners.com/glow-in-the-dark-filament-review/), [metallic](http://colorfabb.com/bronzefill) finish or extra strengh.)

[Woodfill PLA](http://colorfabb.com/woodfill-fine)-like filament might be of extra interest to you, not only because it typically is bio-degradable, but also because it will give you the *look and feel* of being bio-degradable.

Hope that helps!

*PS: there are multiple other filament types that are either recyclable, bio-degradable, or both, although PLA might be the most commonly available of them all.*

Answer (score 1):

Check Green-TEC by [extrudr.eu](http://extrudr.eu/collections/bdp) is made from lignin (wood)
or perhaps Algix Dura. They are both bio degradeable.
Green-TEC ist my favorite because of less warping and [fast printing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oqx170kPmg4).